# Highcharts title as link giving issue in print version

Tags: highcharts

I have highcharts donut and the title of the donut is defined as link through following code:

**title: { 
useHTML: true, 
text: '< a href="mylink" >< u >My title< /u >< /a >',
}**

this page has a print button to have a the donuts in pdf but whne I press print it is showing follwoing for title

**My title (mylink)**

I do not want (mylink) with my title and this happens only in print view. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: How is this print functionality made? Chrome does not give this result.

Comment: Seems to work fine here on Chrome [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61g0k1wr/)

Comment: Luca - can you please tell me how the link is being defined in highcharts as I cannot see any title attribute in your highcharts javascript. I want to see the code so I can compare with mine to figure out whats wrong in mine.

Comment: The link is printed by title: { } object, as a result HTML is generated (a href="">)